# creating MS Release management template failure

Tags: tfsbuild, ms-release-management

Ive been messing around with the Release Management from Microsoft for the past week trying to figure out if it will fit our organization's needs....

First,I've created an Azure no Deployment agent environment using the vNext types (Release, server, component)
My next examination was testing a new Deploy Agents Environment through the same steps, but as i tried to create a Release template it always throws me an 500 internal error everytime.

Mind that i do have:

- Both RM_Server and RM_Client are on the same machine
- Stable connection to the TFS
- Full Admin rights on the machine and the RM
- Created the Servers, Release paths and environments without any errors

stack:

```
Error - (4000, 1928) - The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.: \r\n\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.PlatformHttpClient.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndGetAsyncMemoryStreamFromResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndDownloadString(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClient.EndPost(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.HttpRequestor.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetPostCaller>b__0(String url, String body)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.BaseConfigurationServiceProxy.SetApplicationVersion(String applicationVersionXml)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.ApplicationVersion.Storing()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.ModelBase.Store()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.DetailWorkspaceViewModel.SaveItem(Boolean andRefresh)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.ApplicationVersionViewModel.SaveItem(Boolean andRefresh)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.DetailWorkspaceViewModel.<get_SaveItemCommand>b__0(Object param)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.Helpers.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
```

Comment: Do share the server logs, you can see how it is done here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/13/how-to-enable-detailed-logs-and-collect-traces-from-various-release-management-components.aspx

Comment: stack added to the head msg

Comment: You shared the client logs. Your RM server logs will have more details around what actually went wrong. Do share any exceptions that you see in - C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft\ReleaseManagment\12.0\Logs\ReleaseManagementServices.log in the RM server machine.

Answer (score 0):

might be some of the following

1. TFS registration in RM need to be same as in Build.
2. Opening RM client with "ServiceUser".

Comment: what are you trying to tell?